# How to fix Invalid flag after regular expression in HTML Mail Merge

Tags: google-apps-script

Please help me to fix the mail merge issue, I have attached code where I am getting "Invalid flag after regular expression. (line 41, file "Code")"
Here is the [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sS8_GQ3EMcsXCtj_j8LKg4jywKMu_8symTAFbIkGyh4/edit#gid=0) from where I am importing the data I want to add tables along with some text in the message body.

```js
function DornmatSingle() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:AC2");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var emailAddress = rowData[28];
    var submiterEmail = rowData[1];
    var ProjectName = rowData[2];
    var SrDesign = "Sr. Design Architect Services";
    var PerHourRate = rowData[4];    
    var NumberOfHours = rowData[5];
    var TotalRate = rowData[6];
    var Contact  = "Contact Centre Expert";
    var PerHourRate2 = rowData[8];
    var NumberOfHours2 = rowData[9];
    var NTotalRate2 = rowData[10];
    var NJrDesign = "Jr. Design Architect";
    var PerHourRate3 = rowData[12];
    var NumberOfHours3 = rowData[13];
    var TotalRate3 = rowData[14];
    var Outsourced = "Outsourced Technical Support Resource";
    var PerHourRate4 = rowData[16];
    var NumberOfHours4 = rowData[17];
    var TotalRate4 = rowData[18];
    var Supplier = "Supplier Management";
    var PerHourRate5 = rowData[20];
    var NumberOfHours5 = rowData[21];
    var TotalRate5 = rowData[22];
    var Project = "Project Management & Execution";
    var PerHourRate6 = rowData[24];
    var NumberOfHours6 = rowData[25];
    var TotalRate6 = rowData[26];
    var UserAccount = rowData[28];
    var GrandTotalRate = rowData[27];


 var subject = 'Technology Charges for '+ProjectName+''; 
    var message = <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Verdana; fontsize=9px"><tbody><tr><td style="background-color:#a4fff9;">Sr.No.</td><td style="background-color:#a4fff9;">Cost Element</td><td style="background-color:#a4fff9;">Unit Price</td><td style="background-color:#a4fff9;">UOM
</td><td style="background-color:#a4fff9;">Quantity</td><td style="background-color:#a4fff9;">Total Cost</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Sr. Design Architect Services</td><td> +PerHourRate+ </td><td>Hrs </td><td> +NumberOfHours+ </td><td>+TotalRate+</td></tr></tr><td>2</td><td>Jr. Design Architect</td><td> +PerHourRate3+ </td><td>Hrs </td><td> +NumberOfHours3+ </td><td>+TotalRate3+</td></tr></tr><td>3</td><td>Contact Centre Expert</td><td> +PerHourRate2+ </td><td>Hrs </td><td> +NumberOfHours2+ </td><td> +NTotalRate2+ </td></tbody></table>

   
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: message,
  });

  }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you have not set the content of the variable `message` as a string. Define the message variable as follows or in a suitable manner so that it would still be a string:

```
var message = '<table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Verdana; fontsize=9px"><tbody><tr><td style="background-color:#a4fff9;">Sr.No.</td><td style="background-color:#a4fff9;">Cost Element</td><td style="background-color:#a4fff9;">Unit Price</td><td style="background-color:#a4fff9;">UOM'+
'</td><td style="background-color:#a4fff9;">Quantity</td><td style="background-color:#a4fff9;">Total Cost</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Sr. Design Architect Services</td><td>' +PerHourRate+ '</td><td>Hrs </td><td>' +NumberOfHours+ '</td><td>+TotalRate+</td></tr></tr><td>2</td><td>Jr. Design Architect</td><td>' +PerHourRate3+ '</td><td>Hrs </td><td> +NumberOfHours3+ </td><td>'+TotalRate3+'</td></tr></tr><td>3</td><td>Contact Centre Expert</td><td>' +PerHourRate2+ '</td><td>Hrs </td><td>' +NumberOfHours2+ '</td><td>' +NTotalRate2+ '</td></tbody></table>'
```